# Error when overriding views auth page in django

Tags: python, django

In my project, I have an app namely `account`, I put my `login.html` and `logged_out.html` files in `templates/registration` directory. In `urls`, I use `django.contrib.auth.views` to call the ones, as below

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
        template_name="logged_out.html"), name='logout'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name="registration/login.html"), name='login'),
]
```

The problem is my login page is my login page loaded successful, but the logged_out page is not, it just the default logged_out page. I tried to move the `logged_out.html` file to other directory and it was loaded. 
So my question is why I cannot override the logged_out page while I can do it with login page.

Note: I try with other page like change passwords and still got the same errors.

Comment: One thing from your code though, you didn't append "registration/" to the logged_out.html. Is that just a typo?

Comment: This file is located in `registration` directory.

Comment: Well check what @keni wrote, you forgot to write the full path to your `logged_out.html` file (`registration/` is missing)